# function going back to main

Tags: c, function

I wonder how can I jump back to int main() when i call my function void BMIcalculator(), and what would be the proper logical statement if the user wants to calculate his/her BMI again and again until he/she get tired then press [2] to go back to my home page.

```
void BMIcalculator(){
    system("cls");
    int choice;

    float kg=0,m=0,totalBMI=0;

    do{
        p("[1] calculate BMI    ");
        p("[2] back ");
        s("%d", &choice);

    if( choice == 1){
        gotoxy(1, 1); p("Enter weight :           kilograms");
        gotoxy(1, 2); p("Enter height :           meters");
        gotoxy(1, 3); p("Body Mass Index = ");
        gotoxy(20, 1); s("%f", &kg);
        gotoxy(20, 2); s("%f", &m);
        totalBMI=kg/(m*m);
        gotoxy(20, 3); p("%.2f",totalBMI);

        }else if( choice == 2){
            go back to main;
        }

    }while(choice == 1);
}

int main(){

    int choice;

    p("[1] BMI calculator");
    p("[2] Price calculator");
    p("[3] NATS");
    p("[4] Exit");
    s("%d", &choice);

    if(choice == 1){
        BMIcalculator();
    }
    .....
}
```

Comment: Huh? When returning from a function, it is "jumping" back to the place it was called from...If you want to execute it repeatedly - use loops.

Comment: 'cls' does not work on *inux type systems. however, 'clear' does work. and there is a control sequence that should work everywhere: esc [2j will clear the entire screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the while condition but if you don't want you can just add a return statement:

```
else if(choice == 2){
    return;
}
```

If you want to repeat infinitly, you should add a loop:

```
while(1) {
    p("[1] BMI calculator");
    p("[2] Price calculator");
    p("[3] NATS");
    p("[4] Exit");
    s("%d", &choice);

    if(choice == 1){
        BMIcalculator();
    }
}
```

Comment: i already tried doing that. but whenever i press 2 to go back to my main page. the program stops.

Comment: The program goes out of the function. It will run the code under the function call.

Comment: do{
 system("cls");
 p("[1] calculate BMI ");
 p("[2] back ");
 s("%d", &choice);
 
 if( choice == 1){
  gotoxy(1, 1); p("Enter weight :     kilograms");
  gotoxy(1, 2); p("Enter height :     meters");
  gotoxy(1, 3); p("Body Mass Index = ");
  gotoxy(20, 1); s("%f", &kg);
  gotoxy(20, 2); s("%f", &m);
  totalBMI=kg/(m*m);
  gotoxy(20, 3); p("%.2f",totalBMI);
  getch();
 }else if( choice == 2){
  return;
 }

 }while(choice == 1);

}

Comment: there needs to be an additional change.  specifically, in the `main()` function, the display of the menu and the acting upon the selected menu item needs to be wrapped in a `do...while(4 != choice);` loop

Answer (score 0):

You should use a DO-WHILE that in the while condition controls the input and then restart the "while".

For example:

```
do
  { 
      //your function; 
     scanf(" %d",&choice);
   }
   while(choice==1);
```